# How to create multiple ,csv files in R?

Tags: r, plyr

I have a .csv file with data for different chromosomes. The chromosomes names are stored in the first column(column name: Chr). My aim is to separate the data for each chromosome i.e. (Chr1,Chr2 etc) and make separate csv files for each. I cannot understand how to do this in limited steps.
Thanks

Comment: Could you share your data and code for your homework problem

Answer (score 6):

Illustrating a one liner using `plyr` and the dataset `iris`

```
plyr::d_ply(iris, .(Species), function(x) write.csv(x, 
  file = paste(x$Species, ".csv", sep = "")))
```

Comment: That's a very nifty plyr solution. I've never used the `*_ply()` functions, but this is a great illustration.

Comment: yes the `plyr` package has transformed my thinking. it is amazingly powerful

Answer (score 5):

1. Read Data

   ```
   fn <- dir(pattern="csv")
   data_in <- do.call(rbind,lapply(fn,read.csv))
   ```
2. Split by chromosome

   ```
   data_out <- split(data_in,data_in[[1]])
   ```
3. Write by chromosome

   ```
   chn <- unlist(lapply(data_out,"[",1,1))
   for(i in seq_along(chn)) write.csv(data_out[[i]],file=paste(chn[i],"csv",sep="."))
   ```

Comment: chn <- unlist(lapply(data_out,"[",1,1))
Could you please explain me the meaning of 1,1!

Answer (score 2):

One way is to read the input file one line at a time and append the line to the correct outfile based on the first x characters of the line:

```
con <- file('yourInputFile', 'r') 

while (length(input <- readLines(con, n=1) > 0){ 
      outputfile <- paste(substr(input, 1, 5), ".csv", sep="" ) 
       ### assuming first 5 characters are new file name
      outfile <- file(outputfile, 'a')
      writeLines(output, con=outfile)
      close(outfile)
}
```

The advantage of this approach is that it works even if yourInputFile is too big to read into memory. The downside is that this approach is slow as it does a lot of opening/closing of files.